# View pdf in LyX too slow

Tags: lyx

I have a problem with my LyX software and I would like to have some help from you. I have used LyX for a year, but today the problem is when I view the pdf of my LaTeX file in LyX it runs too slow (about an hour).

Comment: That is slow....

Comment: how long does it take if you just compile a document with the word "hello" ?

Comment: very long, more than 20 minutes such that i can't wait

Comment: @BinhNguyen What operating system are you using? I think something is fundamentally wrong with the system. You might consider installing Ubuntu in a virtual box. Or, try uninstalling and reinstalling LyX, perhaps with a different version.

Comment: Have you tried something as simple as rebooting?

Comment: yes, but it's still slow. then i reinstall all window and programmes. Now it works nice!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by reinstallation of LyX.

Answer (score 1):

In a general way, when you use LaTeX and you want to compile faster, you can add `draft` in the option of your document; for instance:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
```

This mainly remove all the images and replace them with a white square. It also indicates (with big black squares) layout errors that LaTeX fail to resolve itself.

This option makes the compilation faster.

Comment: Yes, but it won't solve the underlying problem if a document containing only "hello world" takes 20 minutes to compile ...